# RSpec: Controller spec with polymorphic resource, "No route matches" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, multi-tenant, polymorphic-associations

I'm learning RSpec by writing specs for an existing project. I'm having trouble with a controller spec for a polymorphic resource Notes. Virtually any other model can have a relationship with Notes like this: `has_many :notes, as: :noteable`

In addition, the app is multi-tenant, where each Account can have many Users. Each Account is accessed by `:slug` instead of `:id` in the URL. So my mulit-tenant, polymorphic routing looks like this:

```
# config/routes.rb
...

scope ':slug', module: 'accounts' do

  ...

  resources :customers do
    resources :notes
  end

  resources :products do
    resources :notes
  end
end
```

This results in routes like this for the :new action

```
new_customer_note GET    /:slug/customers/:customer_id/notes/new(.:format)      accounts/notes#new
new_product_note GET    /:slug/products/:product_id/notes/new(.:format)        accounts/notes#new
```

Now on to the testing problem. First, here's an example of how I test other non-polymorphic controllers, like invitations_controller:

```
# from spec/controllers/accounts/invitation_controller_spec.rb
require 'rails_helper'

describe Accounts::InvitationsController do
  describe 'creating and sending invitation' do
    before :each do
      @owner = create(:user)
      sign_in @owner
      @account = create(:account, owner: @owner)
    end

    describe 'GET #new' do
      it "assigns a new Invitation to @invitation" do
        get :new, slug: @account.slug
        expect(assigns(:invitation)).to be_a_new(Invitation)
      end
    end
    ...
end
```

When i try to use a similar approach to test the polymorphic notes_controller, I get confused :-)

```
# from spec/controllers/accounts/notes_controller_spec.rb

require 'rails_helper'

describe Accounts::NotesController do
  before :each do
    @owner = create(:user)
    sign_in @owner
    @account = create(:account, owner: @owner)
    @noteable = create(:customer, account: @account)
  end

  describe 'GET #new' do
    it 'assigns a new note to @note for the noteable object' do
      get :new, slug: @account.slug, noteable: @noteable     # no idea how to fix this :-)
      expect(:note).to be_a_new(:note)
    end
  end
end
```

Here I'm just creating a Customer as @noteable in the before block, but it could just as well have been a Product. When I run rspec, I get this error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"accounts/notes", :noteable=>"1", :slug=>"nicolaswisozk"}
```

I see what the problem is, but i just can't figure out how to address the dynamic parts of the URL, like `/products/` or `/customers/`.

Any help is appreciated :-)

**UPDATE:**

Changed the `get :new` line as requested below to

```
get :new, slug: @account.slug, customer_id: @noteable
```

and this causes the error

```
Failure/Error: expect(:note).to be_a_new(:note)

 TypeError:
   class or module required
 # ./spec/controllers/accounts/notes_controller_spec.rb:16:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Line 16 in the spec is:

```
expect(:note).to be_a_new(:note)
```

Could this be because the :new action in my notes_controller.rb is not just a `@note = Note.new`, but is initializing a new Note on a @noteable, like this?:

```
def new
  @noteable = find_noteable
  @note = @noteable.notes.new
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the problem here should be that in this line

```
get :new, slug: @account.slug, noteable: @noteable
```

you are passing `:noteable` in params. But, you need to pass all the dynamic parts of the url instead to help rails match the routes. Here you need to pass `:customer_id` in params. Like this,

```
get :new, slug: @account.slug, customer_id: @noteable.id
```

Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks, looks like you're on to something. The routing error is gone, but now it says `TypeError: class or module required`. I guess it's refering to the Customer class. How do I include that in the test?

Comment: can you give some stacktrace for the error? that should help.

Comment: I assume you are trying to check the type of instance variable `@note` assigned inside your action. For that you will have to write `expect(assigns(:note)).to be_a Note` or `expect(assigns(:note)).to be_a_new Note`.

Comment: you need to pass a class or module name to `be_a_new` matcher, but you were passing a symbol only. That's why it raised the error.

Comment: For your help, these are quite good docs here: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs. Just check the version of rspec you are using.

Comment: That was it! Thank you! Of course, the line needed to be `expect(assigns(:note)).to be_a_new(Note)`